# How could I filter this ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist, filter, stream

I wonder how could I filter Posts ArrayList to get all Posts written by John

**This is my code:**

```
    Posts = new ArrayList<>();
    authors = new ArrayList<String>();
    authors.add("John");
    tags = new ArrayList<String>();
    tags.add("space");
    Posts.add(new Post(2, "First Post",authors, "Content", tags));
```

Comment: You need to specify more information like the how various fields are encoded, the relationship between authors and posts,  etc.  Otherwise any solution at this point would be a guess.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
posts.stream()
        .filter(n -> n.getAuthors().contains("John"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

there's a handy removeIf method...

```
posts.removeIf(p -> !p.getAuthors().contains("John"));
```

That `->` represents a function. We're telling the `removeIf` function: To figure out if a certain entry in the list needs to be removed, run the function on it. The function, then says: Given a `p` (which is the Post object), call getAuthors on it, and call `.contains("John")` on that. Then flip the boolean result and voila. If true, remove it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find something by its key (John in this case) you could use hashmap.
It will give you the value for that key. So you can create different posts in an arraylist of strings and different autors like this:

```
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> autors = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> posts= new ArrayList<String>();
    posts.add("Hello");
    posts.add("World.");
    hashmap.put("John", posts);
    System.out.println("Posts by John:"  + autors.get("John"));
```